# Instrumented test is stuck on "Connected to process"

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-instrumentation

When I try to run the **ExampleInstrumentedTest** on my Android Studio project, it builds fine, installs the test and then it is stuck on "`Connected to process ####...`" and no test results are displayed.

I've waited for more than 2 minutes and still no result. When I create a new Android Studio project with Empty Activity, the test runs fine and results are displayed. It's not working unfortunately for my existing project which I had been working on for a long time but never tried to run the Example test.

Things I've tried:

- Restart Physical device
- Uninstall app
- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Clean Project

Here's the screenshot of how it looks like:

[image: Instrumented test results output]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how I solved this problem but these are the changes I made:

- I changed the Kotlin version from 1.6 to 1.7.
- I removed an unnecessary test file Navigation.
- I removed all the unnecessary testing dependencies.
- And, finally I clean built the project and voila. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core` from dependencies did it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).